# How can I show all translations of a field in a node

Tags: 7, views, i18n-l10n, entities

I am working on a relatively simple multilingual site. I only need to translate the title of each node, so I thought a lightweight approach through [entity translation](https://drupal.org/project/entity_translation) and the [title](https://drupal.org/project/title) modules would be the best way to go.

I want to show the original title as well as its translation in the same node, and let users choose which language they want it translated into through a dropdown selector (not the language switcher block as I don't need different URLS or the whole page translated)

I am trying to do this through a views block, providing the node id as an argument and the language selector as an exposed filter. But I can't get my head around it so far: the node title in the block is always the original one (english).

Any thoughts, different approaches, tips, code, module suggestions will be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The entity translation module will expose a "translate" tab for the node. Will that work for you?